# Alternative for Deprecated NSKeyedUnarchiver.UnarchiveTopLevelObject in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, .net-maui

I'm creating a .Net MAUI app, and since I need to render higher number of points to the UI, I'm going platform native to render.

I'm new to IOS, and for performance efficient renderings I have referred the sample given in this [blog](https://medium.com/@almalehdev/high-performance-drawing-on-ios-part-2-2cb2bc957f6), where I'm decoding the existing layer and copying to a new CAShapeLayer. But I'm facing deprecated warning for these below changes.

```
var newDrawingLayer = NSKeyedUnarchiver.UnarchiveTopLevelObject(
                data: NSKeyedArchiver.GetArchivedData(drawingLayer, false, out error), error: out error) as CAShapeLayer;
```

What would be the alternative to achieve this in Xamarin IOS?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved myself. Instead using deprecated UnarchiveTopLevelObject we can use GetUnArchiveObject and additional parameter need to be given which represents type of object to get. Here I'm getting from CAShapeLyer, you can give as object.Class(here it is drawingLayer.Class). The following code solves my problem.

```
  var newDrawingLayer = NSKeyedUnarchiver.GetUnArchiveObject(drawingLayer.Class,
                    data: NSKeyedArchiver.GetArchivedData(drawingLayer, false, out error), error: out error) as CAShapeLayer;
```